# html scroll bar inside scroll box

Tags: html

I am making a scroll box for and i put some code in it , the problem is that the horizontal scroll bar is inside the box instead of belonging to it [image]

```
  <pre>
    <div style="height:300px;width:700px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia,Garamond,Serif;overflow:auto;">
         [code language="cpp"]
         my code...
         [/code]
    </div>
  </pre>
```

I don't see what can cause this behavior.
**UPDATE** the scroll bar inside the scroll box belongs to the `[code]` block and its there whither i use `<div>` or not.

Comment: is it because of the block of code inside ?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: sorry i'm not a native english speaker what do you mean by fiddle ?

Comment: Go to this website: http://jsfiddle.net/ write your html/css/js in the related sections, click `save` and copy-paste the URL.

Comment: I created a sample fiddle with your code and the result doesn't look like your screenshot: http://jsfiddle.net/7wardceu/ Is there any other css rules or js scripts?

Comment: here is the  entire html code : http://jsfiddle.net/hh750vm1/

Comment: In the fiddle - it's looking good. I believe you have more js/css code that you didn't include which affect on the results.

Comment: its in wordpress post edit, and i copied the entire post

Comment: the scroll bar inside the box belongs to  the [code] block

Answer (score 0):

Try changing its position in css with -webkit-scrollbar.

something like:

```
div::-webkit-scrollbar{
     bottom:-10px;
}
```

for more information:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/

Comment: i am using html not css

Comment: The part   style=""   is css. If you prefer not to include a css file try adding this to your html file:
<style type="text/css">
  div::-webkit-scrollbar{
   bottom:-10px;
  }
</style>